# How to get and display the lowest value from an array inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

this is my array:

```
[{
            "AC": "true",
            "doj": "2020-11-20T00:00:00+05:30",
            "fareDetails": [
                {
                    "baseFare": "1033.00",
                    "srtFee": "0.0",
                    "tollFee": "0.0",
                    "totalFare": "1085.00"
                },
                {
                    "baseFare": "1086.00",
                    "srtFee": "0.0",
                    "tollFee": "0.0",
                    "totalFare": "1140.00"
                },
                {
                    "baseFare": "1190.00",
                    "srtFee": "0.0",
                    "tollFee": "0.0",
                    "totalFare": "1250.00"
                },
                {
                    "baseFare": "1243.00",
                    "srtFee": "0.0",
                    "tollFee": "0.0",
                    "totalFare": "1305.00"
                }
            ],
            "fares": [
                "1250.00",
                "1305.00",
                "1140.00",
                "1085.00"
            ],
        },..........],
```

I need to show the lowest "baseFare" among the given array, as there are four base fare i need show only the lowest and it should be in numbers like 1033 without decimals

So far i tried this , but it gives error

```
 Math.round(Math.min(...item.fareDetails.baseFare)
```

How to achive this ?

Comment: [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19590865) -> then get `Math.min` from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the combination of `Math.min` and `yourArry.map`

like this

```
Math.min.apply( Math, t[0].fareDetails.map(x=>x.baseFare))
```

```js
var t =[{
            "AC": "true",
            "doj": "2020-11-20T00:00:00+05:30",
            "fareDetails": [
                {
                    "baseFare": "1033.00",
                    "srtFee": "0.0",
                    "tollFee": "0.0",
                    "totalFare": "1085.00"
                },
                {
                    "baseFare": "1086.00",
                    "srtFee": "0.0",
                    "tollFee": "0.0",
                    "totalFare": "1140.00"
                },
                {
                    "baseFare": "1190.00",
                    "srtFee": "0.0",
                    "tollFee": "0.0",
                    "totalFare": "1250.00"
                },
                {
                    "baseFare": "1243.00",
                    "srtFee": "0.0",
                    "tollFee": "0.0",
                    "totalFare": "1305.00"
                }
            ],
            "fares": [
                "1250.00",
                "1305.00",
                "1140.00",
                "1085.00"
            ],
        },{
            "AC": "true",
            "doj": "2020-11-20T00:00:00+05:30",
            "fareDetails": [
                {
                    "baseFare": "12.00",
                    "srtFee": "0.0",
                    "tollFee": "0.0",
                    "totalFare": "1085.00"
                },
                {
                    "baseFare": "444.00",
                    "srtFee": "0.0",
                    "tollFee": "0.0",
                    "totalFare": "1140.00"
                },
                {
                    "baseFare": "22.00",
                    "srtFee": "0.0",
                    "tollFee": "0.0",
                    "totalFare": "1250.00"
                },
                {
                    "baseFare": "111.00",
                    "srtFee": "0.0",
                    "tollFee": "0.0",
                    "totalFare": "1305.00"
                }
            ],
            "fares": [
                "1250.00",
                "1305.00",
                "1140.00",
                "1085.00"
            ],
        }]
var lowest =Math.min.apply(Math,t.flatMap(x=> x.fareDetails.map(x=>x.baseFare)))
console.log(lowest)
```

Comment: Why Math as the 1st arg to apply()?

Comment: `.map(/* ... */ .map( /* ... */)).join().split(",")`??? Why go through all the trouble for a trivial operation like flattening an array?

Comment: I just want to get all ``baseFare`` in a single Array to process it

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil yes, I'm aware of that. I wonder why convert to a string and split it back into another array instead of just [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)-ping?

Comment: Yes ``flatMap`` is better way to get rid of all ``join`` and ``split`` i have edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract `baseFare` values from the array item and get the min value among them as follows.

```
Math.round(Math.min(...item.map(({ fareDetails: { baseFare } }) => Number(baseFare))));
```